# How can I create a multi-type matrix?

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I have these data :

```
4  pippo pluto paperino
10 marco paolo roberto
2  hello cruel world
```

and I'd like to store these data into a multi-type matrix `myMatrix`. (First field is an integer, the rest are strings).

So, if I type myMatrix[1][2] I must get `paolo`. How can I do it on C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to create a class that represent your data, with 4 fields (integer, string, string, string).

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
    public string Param3 { get; set; }
    public string Param4 { get; set; }
}
```

Then simply use a `List<MyClass>` to store your data.
To get Paolo you'll need to use `List[1].Param2` (also name your parameters with meaningful names).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use arrays to store different types of objects that are not part of the same inheritance chain.

an `object[][]` will work, but you will not have type safety and need to cast to the target type.

You can use `Tuple<int,string,string,string>[]` (introduced in .NET 4.0), though your own simple type would be a more readable option.

Instead of using arrays, you could use one of the collection types - for example `List<T>`, where the generic type is a tuple or your custom type.

You really need to think about the *usage* this collection will be put into before you can select a suitable data structure.

Comment: +1 for Tuple I don't know why people are not adopting it, it is so much less code and it is Factory pattern at its best.

Comment: @SurjitSamra - People either don't know it, or don't want to use it as it has very weak semantics. Personally, I would only use it _within_ a single method, not as part of an API.

Answer (score 4):

```
Tuple<int, string, string, string>[]
object[][]
Dictionary<int, string[]>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Dictionary<int, string[]>` to get such effect:

```
Dictionary<int, string[]> myMatrix = new Dictionary<int, string[]>();
myMatrix.Add(4, new[] { "pippo", "pluto", "paperino" });
...


//get

myMatrix[4][1] == "pluto"
```

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionary<int, string[]>` is the simplest way as I think.

More about `Dictionary` type can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)